# How to remove background color in MATLAB App

Tags: matlab, background-color, figure

I've made an app which, from some dropdown menus, runs a script and generates a set of graphs on the right. I'd like to have the background all white but for some reason am stuck on the below image where the axes are white but the figure remains grey.

[image of graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9F1j.png)

I've tried manually setting the color to 'w' and 'none' in the design view and also tried the below code to set the default values to both 'w' and 'none' as well.

The below code works in a script but not in the app developer code:

```
        set(groot,'DefaultFigureColor','none');
        set(groot,'DefaultAxesColor','none');
```

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Set the color to white!, but of each individual plots, not the app.

Comment: The code below has the same results:

            set(app.UIAxes,'color','w');
            set(app.UIAxes_2,'color','w');
            set(app.UIAxes_3,'color','w');
            set(app.UIAxes_4,'color','w');

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] of a little unrelated demo that replicates this problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the color change to the end of the callback, rather than the start, seems to have fixed it. Not sure why the colors were resetting during generating the graphs.